# How to merge two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Qyery

```
 Select FinancialId,
        ApplicationId,
        UPPER (InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankName) as BankName,    
        InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId,
        BankMaster.BankName as Bank

 From   InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail

 left join BankMaster On BankMaster.BankId = InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
```

This query gave me result like this:

```
FinancialId   ApplicationId     BankName       BankId   Bank
1              1                HARSH BANK        -1    NULL
7              3                                   1    Allahabad Bank
8              3                JFGJFGJ           -1    NULL
```

But i need Column "BankName" and "Bank" to be merged like :

```
FinancialId   ApplicationId     BankName       BankId   
1              1                HARSH BANK        -1    
7              3                Allahabad Bank     1                
8              3                JFGJFGJ           -1
```

Is this possible to get result like i need? IF yes Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this.

```
Select FinancialId,
        ApplicationId,
        ISNULL(UPPER (InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankName),'') + 
        ISNULL(BankMaster.BankName,'')
        as BankName,    
        InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId

 From   InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail

 left join BankMaster On BankMaster.BankId = InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    FinancialId,
    ApplicationId,
    ISNULL(UPPER (InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankName), '')+ISNULL(BankMaster.BankName, '') as BankName,    
    InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
From   
    InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail left join 
        BankMaster On BankMaster.BankId = InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(BankName, Bank)
FROM InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail
```

Comment: Which version of sql server supports keyword `CONCAT`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select FinancialId,
    ApplicationId,
    UPPER (ISNULL(InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankName,''))+''+ISNULL(BankMaster.BankName,'') as BankName,    
    InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId

From   InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail

left join BankMaster On BankMaster.BankId = InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
```

Comment: nitin query is right, but in this case UPPER is inside the ISNULL because Aijaz wants same as field name. not upper case.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `COALESCE` function, it is exactly what you need for this:

```
SELECT FinancialId,
       ApplicationId,
       COALESCE(UPPER(InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankName), BankMaster.BankName) as BankName,    
       InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
FROM   InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail
LEFT JOIN BankMaster 
     ON BankMaster.BankId = InterestSubsidyFinancialDetail.BankId
```